# Find the fraction where the decimal expansion is infinite?

Tags: probability, power-series, generating-functions, fractions

Find the fraction with integers for the numerator and denominator, where the decimal expansion is $0.11235.....$

The numerator and denominator must be less than $100$.

Find the fraction.

I believe I can use generating functions here to get $1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+.....$, but I do not know how to apply it.

Comment: What's the next digit, $8$?

Comment: Good rational approximations can be found using partial fractions.

Comment: @CameronBuie It was not given.

Comment: @barakmanos: Not sure. It was not given.

Comment: Ah! Never mind. I missed the condition that the numerator and denominator must be less than $100.$

Comment: Is the fractional term supposed to be the simple stringing together of the Fibonacci numbers, i.e., `0.112358132134...`?

Answer (score 15):

Like you hint, we can observe that the value
$$0.11235955056\ldots = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} 10^{-k} F_k,$$
where $F_k$ is the $k$th [Fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) (with the convention that $F_0 = 0$, $F_1 = 1$),
is simply the value of the series
$$F(x) := \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} F_k x^k = x + x^2 + 2x^3 + 3x^4 + 5x^5 + 8x^6 + 13x^7 + \cdots$$
at $x = \frac{1}{10}$.

**Hint** Using the defining recurrence relation
$$F_{k + 2} = F_{k + 1} + F_k$$
(and the above convention) gives that $F(x)$ satisfies
$$F(x) = x + x F(x) + x^2 F(x).$$

> Rearranging gives that on the open interval of convergence of the series, which turns out to be $(-1/\phi, 1/\phi)$---where $\phi$ is the [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), and which in particular contains the value $\frac{1}{10}$ of interest)---we have $$F(x) = \frac{x}{1 - x - x^2}.$$ Thus, the series has value $$F\left(\tfrac{1}{10}\right) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)}{1 - \left(\frac{1}{10}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2} = \color{#bf0000}{\boxed{\frac{10}{89}}} .$$ Since this is a rational number, its decimal expansion repeats: $$0.\overline{1123595505617977528089887640449438202247191}.$$

Comment: @FlybyNight yes, that behavior is obvious and expected -- 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 and then the 8 and 13 overlap to give a 9 in the decimal expansion in place of the 8.

Answer (score 6):

Continued fractions:
\begin{align}
\frac{11235}{100000}&=\frac{2247}{20000}\\
&=\cfrac{1}{8+\cfrac{2024}{2247}}\\
&=\cfrac{1}{8+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{223}{2024}}}\\
&=\cfrac{1}{8+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{9+\cfrac{1}{13+\cfrac{2}{17}}}}}\\
&=\cfrac{1}{8+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{9+\cfrac{1}{13+\cfrac{1}{8+\cfrac{1}{2}}}}}}\\
&=[0;8,1,9,13,2]
\end{align}
The first convergent is $1/8$; the second convergent is
$$
\cfrac{1}{8+1}=\frac{1}{9};
$$
the third convergent is
$$
\cfrac{1}{8+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{9}}}=\cfrac{1}{8+\cfrac{9}{10}}=\frac{10}{89};
$$
The fourth convergent can be computed to $131/1166$ (see this [continued fraction calculator](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/cfCALC.html))

Answer (score 3):

An exhaustive search (by computer) of all fractions with numerator and denominator $< 100$ shows there is only one whose decimal representation starts 0.11235:
$$
\frac{10}{89}
$$

The decimal expansion continues $\ldots 955056179775\ldots$ (I haven't bothered finding aprogram that can calculate enough that we can see the period), that's completely impossible to guess- I would call the question poorly worded.

Comment: To save anyone from having to reach for a calculator, the first many digits of the expansion goes $0.1123595505617977\dots$.  The question of if there is a better method than brute force remains.  We could clearly see that for it to work for some $\frac{p}{q}$, we would need $8.5p < q<9p$ and so $p\leq 11$, reducing cases to test to less than 18

Comment: @Henrik: I am guessing that the decimal representation would represent Fibonacci numbers, but I'm not sure..

Comment: The period is $44$ since $m = 44$ is the smallest positive integer such that $10^m \equiv 1 \pmod{89}$. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%2F89) gives the decimal expansion to enough digits.

Comment: @MathisLife: I would be surprised if the decimal representation of the Fibonacci numbers were rational.

Answer (score 0):

These are fractions $f$ with $11235/100000\le f<11236/100000.$ A direct, if slow, method for counting these would be
$$
\sum_{d=1}^{100}\left\lfloor\frac{100000d}{11235}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{100000d}{11236}\right\rfloor
$$

or

```
sum(d=1,100,100000*d\11235-100000*d\11236)
```